# Fixing app that works locally but not on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am a newbie in heroku and node.js and I would like to get to know how these work. I tried the tutorial given by heroku. Everthing is fine until [this step](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#push-local-changes). I pushed and tried to open in on the web, but [doesn't work](https://immense-oasis-20574.herokuapp.com/cool). Logs said it cannot find the module, meanwhile I've installed it using npm.

I tried 3 times using different new clone but nonetheless none worked. I also copied all the index.js script given on the tutorial.

index:

```
const cool = require('cool-ascii-faces')
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

express()
  .use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
  .set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
  .set('view engine', 'ejs')
  .get('/', (req, res) => res.render('pages/index'))
  .get('/cool', (req, res) => res.send(cool()))
  .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`))
```

logs:

```
2019-05-09T09:56:08.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-05-09T09:56:08.892352+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2019-05-09T09:56:08.986034+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2019-05-09T09:56:09.884923+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2019-05-09T09:56:11.789509+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-05-09T09:56:11.800910+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-05-09T09:56:11.773890+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-05-09T09:56:11.731995+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
2019-05-09T09:56:11.732041+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2019-05-09T09:56:11.732043+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-05-09T09:56:11.732044+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-05-09T09:56:11.732045+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'cool-ascii-faces'
2019-05-09T09:56:11.732047+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
2019-05-09T09:56:11.732048+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
2019-05-09T09:56:11.732049+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
2019-05-09T09:56:11.732050+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
2019-05-09T09:56:11.732052+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:1:76)
2019-05-09T09:56:11.732053+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
2019-05-09T09:56:11.732054+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
2019-05-09T09:56:11.732055+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
2019-05-09T09:56:11.732056+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
2019-05-09T09:56:11.732058+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
2019-05-09T09:56:14.928577+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2019-05-09T09:56:17.311684+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-05-09T09:56:17.291125+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-05-09T09:56:17.224570+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
2019-05-09T09:56:17.224594+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2019-05-09T09:56:17.224596+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-05-09T09:56:17.224598+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-05-09T09:56:17.224600+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'cool-ascii-faces'
2019-05-09T09:56:17.224601+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
2019-05-09T09:56:17.224603+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
2019-05-09T09:56:17.224605+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
2019-05-09T09:56:17.224609+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
2019-05-09T09:56:17.224610+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:1:76)
2019-05-09T09:56:17.224612+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
2019-05-09T09:56:17.224614+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
2019-05-09T09:56:17.224615+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
2019-05-09T09:56:17.224617+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
2019-05-09T09:56:17.224618+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
2019-05-09T09:56:19.017142+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/cool" host=immense-oasis-20574.herokuapp.com request_id=b24f9916-5042-4b41-9034-e5421063b37f fwd="87.187.232.81" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-09T10:09:56.847796+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=immense-oasis-20574.herokuapp.com request_id=62b8f104-be58-49f5-9b45-82603b0cc1a9 fwd="87.187.232.81" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: From what i read, you don't need to install cool-ascii-faces, this step is just to show how to intall other dependencies once u have your app deployed, so try avoiding this particular step. In the other hand, seems that heroku server can't find the package so most likely it isn't on package.json, to do so run npm install --save cool-ascii-faces so it'll be included on package.json and therefore it'll be installed in heroku.

Comment: Do you have `cool-ascii-faces` packages on your package.json file? If not you have installed this globally.

Comment: @vitomadio I see. I thought that because I already have the cool-ascii-faces on my node_modules folder, it shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: And also, I thought by using npm install, the packages are available online then I don't have to download it on my app. So, do I have to download all the package needed to run the app?

Comment: No, in fact you don't have to commit node_modules folder either to heroku or github, heroku automatically will run npm install on your repo generating a new node_modules inside the repo.

Answer (score 1):

You have to run `npm install --save cool-ascii-faces`.

Heroku get the packages from your package.json and not from the node_modules folder. You should actually never commit it by adding it to your .gitignore file.